# Secure JSF Application (Login) with Glassfish

Tags: mysql, jsf, authentication, glassfish

I'm trying to secure my JSF Application. I am using a JDBC MySQL connection. The password is hashed using SHA-256 function. The j_security_check is always redirecting me to error.xhtml page.

Username: admin
Password: admin

This is the MySQL database tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `group`;
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `groupname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `useranme` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupname`,`useranme`),
  KEY `user_group_fk_idx` (`useranme`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_group_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`useranme`) REFERENCES `user` (`username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

> INSERT INTO `group` VALUES ('admin','admin');

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('admin','8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918','Administrator','2014-03-21 15:03:42');
```

- I've created a new JDBC Connection Pools called UserDB //ping succeeded

> Resource type: javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
>
> I've created a new JDBC Resources called jdbc/user (JNDI Name)
>
> I've created a new Realm with these fields: (Realm name = "userdb")
>
> JAASContext = "jdbcRealm"
>      JNDI = "jdbc/user"
>      UserTable = "user"
>      UserNameColumn = "username"
>      PasswordColumn = "password"
>      GroupTable = "group"
>      GroupNameColumn = "groupname"
>      DigestAlgorithm = "SHA-256"
>      PasswordEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES"

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Admin Security</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>userdb</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

**glassfish-web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

And this is the login page:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
   Username:<input type="text" name="j_username"/><br/>
   Password:<input type="password" name="j_password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a diagnosis. *how* is it not working? And where is the security configuration in your web.xml?

Comment: It is always redirecting me to the error.xhtml page.

Comment: Then what kind of error? an HTTP 500? No accompanying stacktrace?

Comment: no this is the page that I have created not a server error page. It seems that the username/password validation isn't working correctly there's a mistake somewhere in the realm config, the .xml files or don't know..

Comment: Experiment with `BASIC` security first, instead of `FORM` to limit the complexity and isolate probable causes

Comment: @kolossus any idea please?
Do you have any simple full documentation link at least?

Comment: I'm quite surprised that even BASIC authentication is not working. Other than bad config, it's supposed to be foolproof. Are you sure you  tried BASIC (without any fancy stuff: hashing or encryption)? [Here's a tutorial](http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/glassfish-basic-authentication/) on basic GF authentication config

Comment: Yes I'm surprised too, I think that's I'm missing a step that I want to know it. By the way I've tried ldapRealm and it did work correctly! Thank you anyway @kolossus